# ios: Secure a connection to a webserver so that only the app can communicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, security, https

I'm trying to establish some kind of web service from an iOS app to a web server. I know that HTTPS is the way to secure the connection itself (as it encrypts the data which is transferred).

But now I'd like to get some authentication, which allows only the app itself to access the web interface. With reverse engineering it would be possible to find out the URL of the web interface (or maybe also any credentials which are hard coded in the binary). Users how get this information could be able to access the webservice and might do bad things... This is why I want to prevent access to the web interface outside of the app.

Us there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some reading about Securing a web-service, you can start from below:

[OAuth Introduction](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/wiki/GTMOAuthIntroduction)

[Designing a Secure REST (Web) API](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/)

Plus take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923208/how-to-secure-web-service-without-login).

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, but with OAuth and/or a secure REST API the problem of decompiling the app to get the private key still remains. With that a user can manually build the hashes and communicate with the server. But this is what I want to prevent. Only the app itself should be able to talk to the server. Any chance for that?

Comment: You can save this private key in the device keychain and no body can get it.

Comment: Another option: I did this once for a licensing module, I encrypted a token using the device UDID and send it as a credential (or hash) along with the request, and the server encrypts and authenticate this token using the devices's UDID which is saved on server during a registration process.