# How to secure web services coming from only android app to server without login

Tags: java, android, rest, security, authentication

This kind of question is already ask for IOS
    [How To Secure Web Service Without Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923208/how-to-secure-web-service-without-login)

but still I am not able to find the solution to make the web service secure without user authentication.
I have a web service made specially for android app as of now. I want that all the api hit should be only from my android app to the server. No one hack it and hits the api from restclient or postman. 
How server will identify that request is coming from android app explictly the developed one and respond accordingly.

Method 1
I thought to do generate an api key and send that api key in request header which can be verified at server end. If key matches then server can assume the request is coming from whitelisted android app. But problem is that key has to be present inside android app which can be easily decompiled and can be hacked. Attacker may send api request directly from there app/web/ios rest client after obtaining the key .

Method 2
Api key can be easily stolen even kept in sharedprefernce. So i kept that in native code using jni which can not be decompiled, but that code can be dessembled and key can be read from there. So keeping the key within apk is unsecure. So this approach failed.

Method 3
I thought not to keep the original key inside app initially. but to use Asymmetric Keys. Private key was kept at server and encrypted key which got generated from public key was kept in android app.
API is called with input as encrypted key and server decrypts API key using private key and returns that key in response. that key is kept in the application scope and for subsequent request that key is sent in headers. So from now request becomes unsecured as original key is not known to attacker. but problem comes here
that 
encrypted key + 1st api is exposed in the  apk

Hacker will call the Api sending encrypted key along with url and get the actual key in response then that key can be used anywhere. So question is how to secure it so that no one can exploit the resources without login. I have to ensure that hit is coming from app only.

Method 4 It required login with google providing JWT Id token which can be easily verified at server end. but I dont want user to login with google. Just to know request is coming from android app only.

Comment: are you satisfied with the answer? I assume you not. Neither do i. Can you please share your research on this topic. What was the solution which you opted at the end ?

Comment: **read it** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923208/how-to-secure-web-service-without-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923208/how-to-secure-web-service-without-login)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the only possible secure option is option 4.

In any case android app can be easily hacked without having 3rd party service that verifies correctness of the token.You don't have a choice.